# Affix element on scroll

Tags: react-native

I would like to play exactly this [behavior](http://rawgit.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky/master/examples/basic/index.html).

A `Tab` component within a ScrollView should remain affix under the navbar when scroll, the problem is that applying the absolute position to the tab that relates to ScrollView.
This is the structure:

```
<ScrollView
      style={styles.scrollView}
      onScroll={this.onScroll}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}>
      <Image source={....} />
      <Tab>...</Tab>
      <View style={[styles.content, props.scrollableViewStyle]}>
          // lorem ipsum..
      </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Image:

[image]

How can I play this in React Native?